# Request timed out is not logging in server side Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

I have set `server timeout in cassandra as 60 seconds` and `client timeout in cpp driver as 120 seconds`.

I use Batch query which has 18K operations, I get the `Request timed out` error in `cpp driver logs` but in Cassandra server logs there is **no TRACE available** in spite of enabling **ALL** logs in Cassandra logback.xml

So how can I confirm that It is thrown from the server / client side in Cassandra?

Answer (score 1):

BATCH is not intended to work that way.  It’s designed to apply 6 or 7 mutations to different tables atomically.  You’re trying to use it like it’s RDBMS counterpart (Cassandra just doesn’t work that way).  The BATCH timeout is designed to protect the node/cluster from crashing due to how expensive that query is for the coordinator.

In the system.log, you should see warnings/failures concerning the sheer size of your BATCH.  If you’ve modified them and don’t see that, you should see a warning about a timeout threshold being exceeded (I think BATCH gets its own timeout in 3.0).

If all else fails, run your BATCH statement (part of it) in cqlsh with tracing on, and you’ll see precisely why this is a bad idea (server side).

Also, the default query timeouts are there to protect your cluster.  You really shouldn’t need to alter those.  You should change your query/model or approach before looking at adjusting the timeout.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am not able to see these timeout / sheer size warn / errors in system.log

Comment: please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642682/enable-one-time-cassandra-authentication-and-authorization-check-and-cache-it-fo

Comment: @Harry That question has nothing to do with this one, from what I can see.