# Why connection is timing out frequently

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

As a follow up on this question : [Enable one time Cassandra Authentication and Authorization check and cache it forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642682/enable-one-time-cassandra-authentication-and-authorization-check-and-cache-it-fo)

I would like to understand that I get `Request timed Out` error and If I see in the server logs I get only following error.

```
ERROR [SharedPool-Worker-34] 2018-06-01 10:40:36,589 ErrorMessage.java:338 - Unexpected exception during request
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.
        at org.apache.cassandra.auth.CassandraRoleManager.getRole(CassandraRoleManager.java:489) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.auth.CassandraRoleManager.getRoles(CassandraRoleManager.java:269) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.auth.RolesCache.getRoles(RolesCache.java:66) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.auth.Roles.hasSuperuserStatus(Roles.java:51) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at org.apache.cassandra.auth.AuthenticatedUser.isSuper(AuthenticatedUser.java:71) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
```

I understand that I didn't enable the caching of Authentication and Authorization in cassandra.yaml but still I **Could somebody explain why I get this error frequently, Is it a costly performance operation in Cassandra?**

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the default Cassandra user it is a normal query with QUORUM, any other user should be using LOCAL_ONE. So in terms of "operation cost" is not anything abnormal. But given the error message (this part in specific: "Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.") means you probably have overloaded nodes that can't respond to your queries.

A quick look into your nodes using **nodetool tpstats** would show if you're having problems serving your reads (Look for **blocked**, **all time blocked** and/or **DROPPED** reads).

Auth queries are done with every query you do (AFAIK), so you should enable caches for them (and avoiding overloading your cluster)

Relevant documentation: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/secureConfigNativeAuth.html