# credentials_validity_in_ms in Cassandra seems invalid

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

I get the following error when I add the property : `credentials_validity_in_ms` in `cassandra.yaml`, Is there an issue with this property.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html

```
INFO  [main] 2018-06-03 06:11:30,336 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:85 - Configuration location: file:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
DEBUG [main] 2018-06-03 06:11:30,342 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:102 - Loading settings from file:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
ERROR [main] 2018-06-03 06:11:30,458 CassandraDaemon.java:698 - Exception encountered during startup
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Invalid yaml. Please remove properties [credentials_validity_in_ms] from your cassandra.yaml
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader$MissingPropertiesChecker.check(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:188) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:119) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:95) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:135) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.<clinit>(DatabaseDescriptor.java:119) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:532) [apache-cassandra-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
```

**Cassandra version** : 3.0.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see in the [tags for commit](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/commit/186777aac55b1aa95c5c9e9cdaff2b981cf9d5af) where this configuration parameter was introduced, it's available starting with Cassandra 3.4, and wasn't backported to 3.0.x

Comment: Thanks @Alex  How can I handle this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642682/enable-one-time-cassandra-authentication-and-authorization-check-and-cache-it-fo in Cassandra 3.0.8 ?

Comment: I believe that we're trying to cure wrong problem... Let chat on the channel