# Impact of increasing roles_validity_in_ms & permissions_validity_in_ms

Tags: cassandra, datastax

We are seeing lot of Operation Time Out Exception in our 3 node Cassandra Cluster. Below is portion of error stack.

```
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2203) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3937) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3941) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4824) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
at org.apache.cassandra.auth.PermissionsCache.getPermissions(PermissionsCache.java:72) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Operation timed out - received only 0 responses.
    at org.apache.cassandra.auth.CassandraRoleManager.getRole(CassandraRoleManager.java:489) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.auth.CassandraRoleManager.isSuper(CassandraRoleManager.java:293) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.auth.Roles.hasSuperuserStatus(Roles.java:52) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.auth.AuthenticatedUser.isSuper(AuthenticatedUser.java:71) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.auth.CassandraAuthorizer.authorize(CassandraAuthorizer.java:76) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
```

Every time we see this exception related to either PermissionsCache or CassandraRoleManager. After little research I found a solution to increase roles_validity_in_ms & permissions_validity_in_ms. Thanks to [Enable one time Cassandra Authentication and Authorization check and cache it forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642682/enable-one-time-cassandra-authentication-and-authorization-check-and-cache-it-fo)

*Question here is what is impact of increasing this value?* Datastax documentation says the cache is effective at small duration.

> How long permissions in cache remain valid to manage performance
>   impact of permissions queries. Fetching permissions can be resource
>   intensive. Set the cache validity period to your security tolerances.
>   The cache is used for the standard authentication and the row-level
>   access control (RLAC) cache. The cache is quite effective at small
>   durations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These parameters control how long the permissions & list of roles stay valid during the current session. It heavily dependent on your business requirements - if your application needs that roles & permissions could be changed "online" during work, then you need to have lower values, if it's ok to have the same roles & permissions until next reconnect/restart of app, then you can go to higher values.

But you can also have a combination of both, if you'll use `roles_update_interval_in_ms`, `credentials_update_interval_in_ms` & `permissions_update_interval_in_ms` to lower values than `roles_validity_in_ms`, `credentials_interval_in_ms`, and `permissions_interval_in_ms` (see [doc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html#configCassandra_yaml__roles_update_interval_in_ms)). If these values are specified, then roles, permissions & credentials will be checked in background in given intervals, and if request succeeds, then the cache will be updated, and if it fails, then cached value still will be used.  For example, you can set `roles_validity_in_ms` to 1 day, and `roles_update_interval_in_ms` to 10 minutes, so you'll able to relatively quickly react to changes in the roles for given user.

Comment: I have one more question here - is there any way I can reproduce this exception? I have tried using cassandra-stress, but did not see "Operation timed out" error.

Comment: It could be hard to reproduce it - you need to overload your machines. The most probably this could happen if you use cassandra user with multiple nodes, as for this user the QUORUM CL is used (if you setup correct replication for system_auth keyspace)